# Asp.net controls are not accessible in code behind. Getting error 'The name 'txtUserEmail' does not exist in the current context'

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I don't know where I am making a mistake. whenever I am trying to access textbox in cs file, getting error 'The name 'txtUserEmail' does not exist in the current context'

tempSendEmail.aspx.cs

```
namespace MEPEmailServiceClient
{
    public partial class tempSendEmail : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
            MepClient c = new MepClient();
            var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-U8N2419N;Initial Catalog=Employee;Integrated Security=True");
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into [empDetail] values(@UserEmail)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserEmail",txtUserEmail.Text.ToString());
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();           
            c.sendMail(txtUserEmail.Text.ToString());
            }
            catch(FaultException fe)
            {
                Response.Write(fe.Message);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

tempSendEmail.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="tempSendEmail.aspx.cs" Inherits="MEPEmailServiceClient.tempSendEmail" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUserEmail" />
            <br />

            <asp:Button ID="btnSignUp" runat="server" OnClick="btnSignUp_Click" Text="SignUp" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <a href="EmailLog.aspx">EmailLog.aspx</a><br />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It is missing in the code-behind file. Find the `*Designer.cs`/switch to [Design] on the aspx page (in visual studio) and add `protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtUserEmail;`

Comment: Thank you Frank for the quick reply. Adding a new designer file helped me out to fix the issue.